# Java - Unable to get the values from retrieved serialized object

Tags: java, oracle, io, oracle11g

This code has caused me lots of trouble so far but it's really first class I write to use preparedStatement, Oracle, and serialization. So I am asking for your patience.
The following is the code:

```
 public static boolean storeInfo(Reservation rsv) throws
        IOException, SQLException{
    try {
          //Connection to DB
          Connection con = null;
          Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
          con=DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:@odsdsd",
            "SMBDB",
            "hpdbsmb");
          con.setAutoCommit(false);
          ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream() ;
          ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
          out.writeObject(rsv);
          out.flush();
          out.close();
          byte[] buf = bos.toByteArray();
          //inserting into database
          PreparedStatement prepareStatement = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO 
           SMD_RESERVATION_INSTANCES VALUES(?,?,?)");
          localIDTest = getUniqueID();
          System.out.println("ID: "+localIDTest);
          prepareStatement.setString(1, localIDTest);
          prepareStatement.setBytes(2, buf);
          prepareStatement.setString(3, "Pending");
          prepareStatement.executeUpdate();
          prepareStatement.close();
          con.commit();
   }catch(SQLException sqle){
       System.err.print(sqle);
   }
   catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
       System.err.print(cnfe);
   }
    return false;
   }


   public static Reservation retrieveReservation()throws IOException,
        SQLException{
   Reservation testRsv = new Reservation();
   try {
        Connection con = null;

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:@dsdsds",
            "SMBDB",
            "hpdbsmb");
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
       try {

            PreparedStatement prepareStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM 
             SMD_RESERVATION_INSTANCES WHERE id = ?");         
            prepareStatement.setString(1, localIDTest);
            ResultSet rset = prepareStatement.executeQuery();
            prepareStatement.executeUpdate();
            //prepareStatement.close();
            con.commit();
            if(rset.next()){
                retrievedID = rset.getString("ID");
                Blob blob = rset.getBlob("RESERVATIONINST");
                status = rset.getString("STATUS");
                long blobLength = blob.length();
                int pos = 1;   // position is 1-based
                //int len = 10;
                byte[] bytes = blob.getBytes(pos,(int) blobLength);
                InputStream is = blob.getBinaryStream();
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
                testRsv=(Reservation)ois.readObject();
            }


        rset.close();
        con.close();
         }catch(IOException ioe){
              System.err.print(ioe);
          }
       }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
          System.err.print(cnfe);
      }
    return testRsv;

   }

   public static void displayRsvContent(){

    try{
        Reservation rsvtester = new Reservation();
        rsvtester.badgeNo = 750752;
        rsvtester.networkID = "GHAMKS1C";
        storeInfo(rsvtester);
        rsvReturned = retrieveReservation();
        if(rsvReturned == null){
            System.out.println("Null Reservation!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Badge: " + rsvReturned.badgeNo);
            System.out.println("Network: " + rsvReturned.networkID);
        }

    }catch(SQLException sqle){
            System.err.print(sqle);
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        System.err.print(ioe);
    }
  }


public static void main(String[]args){
    displayRsvContent();
}
```

This is just testing that storing and retrieving the object is done correctly. I create an instance of Reservation and assign its variables values to see if they are actually saved. Surprise surprise they aren't showing up when loading. This is what I get:

```
ID: ec561507-7138-4468-98a3-7756219f216e
Badge: 0
Network: null
```

Why is this happening even though am simply assigning it before storing the object? The id shows though is correct.

P.S. Reservation:

```
public class Reservation implements
   java.io.Serializable{

String eventTitle;
public Date startDate;
public Date endDate;
String requestType;
public int terminals;
String lastName;
String firstName;
String middleInitials;
public transient int badgeNo;
public transient String networkID;
String telephoneNo;
String orgCode;
String orgName;
String justification;
String insideCheckRange;
int mapSize;



MapStorage mapStorage = new MapStorage();


public Reservation(int badgeNo, String networkID) {
    this.badgeNo = badgeNo;
    this.networkID = networkID;
}


    public Reservation(){

    }

public Reservation(String eventTitle, Date startDate, Date endDate, String requestType, int terminals, String lastName, String firstName, String middleInitials, int badgeNo, String networkID, String telephoneNo, String orgCode, String justification) {
    //create in here

    this.eventTitle = eventTitle;
    this.startDate = startDate;
    this.endDate = endDate;
    this.requestType = requestType;
    this.terminals = terminals;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.middleInitials = middleInitials;
    this.badgeNo = badgeNo;
    this.networkID = networkID;
    this.telephoneNo = telephoneNo;
    this.orgCode = orgCode;
    this.justification = justification;
}



 public boolean checkRange() {    



        DateTime startx = new DateTime(startDate.getTime());
        DateTime endx = new DateTime(endDate.getTime());

        //booking status
        boolean possible = false;

        //Booking type: 1 = Project, 2 = Training

        /*
        if(requestType.equals("Project")){
            bookingType = 1;
        }else if(requestType.equals("Training")){
            bookingType = 2;

        }
        */
        //produces submap
        //mapSize = bookingType;
        TreeMap<DateTime, Integer> mapLoaded = null;
        try{
         mapLoaded = mapStorage.RetrieveMap();
        }catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            System.err.print(ioe);
        }
        if(requestType.equals("Project"))
        {
            //Project
            //insideCheckRange = "In first for loop";
            //fetch all values for keys in the map between start and end
                for (Integer capacity : mapLoaded.subMap(startx, endx).values()) {


                    if(capacity >= terminals)
                        //yes then its possible, set to true
                        possible = true;
                    else if(capacity < terminals)
                        //not then set it to false
                        possible = false;

                }

                if(possible == true)
                {

                    //if it is possible to accomodate request
                    for (DateTime x : mapLoaded.subMap(startx, endx).keySet()) {
                    {
                        //for dates n, update value for next operation
                        mapLoaded.put(x, mapLoaded.get(x) - terminals);
                    }
                }
                }else{
                 //nothing now
                }
        }else if(requestType.equals("Training")){
            //Training
             for (Integer capacity : mapLoaded.subMap(startx, endx).values()) {
                    //Provides an insight into capacity accomodation possibility
                    //testValue++;
                    terminals = 1;
                    if(capacity >= terminals)
                        possible = true;
                    else if(capacity < terminals)
                        possible = false;

                }


                if(possible == true)
                {
                    for (DateTime x : mapLoaded.subMap(startx, endx).keySet()) {
                    {
                        //46 so that all seats are reserved
                        mapLoaded.put(x, mapLoaded.get(x) - 46);

                    }
                }
                }else{
                 //nothing now
                }

        }


        return possible;
}

}
```

Comment: no I haven't :( should I do that?

Comment: ok will add it but its proper messy

Comment: why you use executeUpdate() after executeQuery() !! and tray to use getters/setters instead of accessing properties in C# style !!

Comment: @FGraviton did remove it just now but really nothing changed. yes because am working on C# too so maybe the after effect :(

Comment: Where is the code that retrieves and prints the output you posted?

Comment: @gurung displayRsvContent() method shown above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `transient` fields in `Reservation` that would explain it.

But, I think that the problem is that you are actually displaying the dummy `Reservation` that you created at the start of `retrieveReservation()`.

Why?  Because `rset.next()` is returning `false`.

Why?  Well take a look at this:

```
   PreparedStatement prepareStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM 
         SMD_RESERVATION_INSTANCES WHERE id = ?");         
   prepareStatement.setString(1, localIDTest);
   ResultSet rset = prepareStatement.executeQuery();
   prepareStatement.executeUpdate();
   //prepareStatement.close();
   con.commit();
```

That's pretty random.  You don't need to do both an `executeQuery` and an `executeUpdate` on the same prepared statement.  And there's no need to `commit()` at that point because this is a query!

So, what I think is happening is that your spurious call to `executeUpdate` is closing the `ResultSet` so that when you call `rset.next()` it is returning `false`.  (Another possible cause of `rset.next()` returning false would be if your earlier insert had failed / not committed.)

Anyway, if `rset.next()` returns false, your code doesn't even try to deserialize a retrieved object ... and you end up returning the dummy object.

Comment: This explains it perfectly. +1.

Comment: perfect answer really! Thanks so much for taking the time and investing effort in examining the possibilities. The thing was solved by removing con.commit(). It is now returning the values.

Answer (score 0):

You have transient fields in your `Reservation` class:

```
public transient int badgeNo;
public transient String networkID;
```

Java serialization will [avoid storing transient fields](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/):

> You must mark transient any field that either cannot be serialized or
>   any field you do not want serialized. Serialization does not care
>   about access modifiers such as private -- all nontransient fields are
>   considered part of an object's persistent state and are eligible for
>   persistence.

A simple fix is to make those fields non-transient.

Comment: there were non-transient and per the comment above I changed them. Both cases didn't work

Comment: @sys_debug: That means you need to remove the `transient` keyword.

Comment: yes I did remove them but nonetheless nothing changed. the same output u see above is shown again.

Comment: what is the purpose of "byte[] bytes = blob.getBytes(pos,(int) blobLength);" Try removing that, it might be affecting how "blob.getBinaryStream()" works. Also, check the length of the byte arrays you are saving and retrieving and whether they match.